# The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again. LARAVEL 5.6

Tags: laravel, forms, middleware, laravel-5.6, login-script

I need some help. I don't know, what's wrong with my code, yesterday it works fine, but when I'm trying to change the user this is what happened
[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN5Wj.jpg)

and this is my [CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvKKn.jpg)

I've tried to find the solution on the internet but some of them are saying that I didn't use them

> {{csrf_field()}}

as you see on my code, I think I had nothing wrong, please help me :')

Comment: just to understand the code, why there is a hidden input field named '_token' right above the image span?

Comment: Try to replace `{{csrf_field()}} ` with `@csrf` and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Laravel 5.6 using Blades templates, it's pretty easy.

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile">
    @csrf
    ...
</form>
```

It doesn't work, then Refresh the browser cache and now it might work. (When we update our application, a browser may still use old files. If you don’t clear your cache, Old files can access problems when you apply)

For more details open link:- [CSRF Protection in Laravel 5.6](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf)

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and i notify there's another hidden field `_token` with that name in the Captcha control group, Laravel CSRF field also use `_token` hidden field, i think problem causing is this thing. You can simple change Captcha token field name and try.